# Typescript: Use child object from list of parent objects

Tags: arrays, typescript

Fairly new to TypeScript.
I have an array of Animals and want to use them separately, but I can't figure out how to do it.

So I defined my array:

```
animalList : Animal[];
```

To that array I added objects from different Child classes of Animal (Fish, Cat,...).
These child classes have some shared properties and methods and I have no problem using those and I can check with instanceof what kind of Child it is, but I have trouble using properties and calling methods of the specific Child classes.
Example I know the third entry is a Fish due to instanceof, but can't call it's method 'blub()'.

```
animalList[2].blub()
```

How can I access the full functionality of the Child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the array object into a temporary variable, then type checking will work

```
let f = animalList[2]
if(f instanceof Fish) {
   f.blub()
}
```

Comment: Oh god, that was such a simple solution. Thanks a lot dude.